# Show/Hide toggle button is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am fairly new to jQuery and I tried to create a show/hide toggle button without using jQuery's toggle function and I can't figure out what's wrong with the following code.

The Hide button hides the paragraph successfully. The hide part is working. It adds a class "show" and removes class "hide" and changes button's text. I used Dev Tools to see this and this part is working but clicking on the button again is not working i.e the show part.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hide").click(function() {
    $(".content").hide();
    $(this).addClass("show");
    $(this).removeClass("hide");
    $(this).text("Show");
  });
  $(".show").click(function() {
    $(".content").show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="content">If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>
<button class="hide">Hide</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `toggle()` to easily switch the visible state of an element using a single button. Then you can provide a function to `text()` to set the text on the button based on its current value. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".toggle").click(function() {
    $(".content").toggle();
    $(this).text(function(i, t) {
      return t == 'Show' ? 'Hide' : 'Show';
    })
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="content">If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>
<button class="toggle">Hide</button>
```

If you wanted to do this without `toggle()`, then you could use `toggleClass()` to switch the state of the `hide` class, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".toggle").click(function() {
    $(".content").toggleClass('hide');
    $(this).text(function(i, t) {
      return t == 'Show' ? 'Hide' : 'Show';
    })
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="content">If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>
<button class="toggle">Hide</button>
```

Comment: I knew about the toggle function. I wanted to do this without it.

Comment: For what reason? It's the most appropriate thing you need to use here. Anything else is redundant.

Comment: I am a beginner in JavaScript, I just wanted to try it. That's how you learn isn't it?

Comment: Very good point. I've updated the answer to show you an alternative to `toggle()`, although the former is the better approach.

Comment: As other answers have pointed out, I can also attach events using "on()" to solve this but I like this CSS solution also. Thanks Sir.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to change the class - if you do you need to delegate so the event is registered to a static container like document

```
$(document).on("click",".hide",function() {
```

I suggest to toggle instead:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".but").on("click",function() {
    $(".content").toggle();
    $(this).text($(this).text()=="Show"?"Hide":"Show");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="content">If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>
<button class="but">Hide</button>
```

Without toggle

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click",".hide",function() {
    $(".content").hide();
    $(this).text("Show")
      .removeClass("hide")
      .addClass("show");
  });
  $(document).on("click",".show",function() {
    $(".content").show();
    $(this).text("Hide")
      .removeClass("show")
      .addClass("hide");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="content">If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>
<button class="hide">Hide</button>
```

Comment: This works, but how? What's the difference besides that you attached the click event using "on"?

Comment: I attached the click event to the DOCUMENT not to the button which disappeared from the jQuery when you changed the class

Answer (score 0):

The click event only works when the element you add it to is built when the DOM is first created.  As soon as you change the class name of the button from 'show' to 'hide' this "removes it from the DOM" in an event based sense.

To get the button click event to trigger after you change the class name on the button you must assign the click event using the on() function and the function must be placed on the parent container of the element that will trigger the event.  In the example below I have added the on() method to the document object, so all elements within the document that have a class of .hide or .show will inherit these click events.  This will also apply to any new elements you create on the fly.

```
<p class="content">If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>
<button class="hide">Hide</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).on('click', ".show", function(){
        $(".content").show();
        $(this).addClass("hide");
        $(this).removeClass("show");
        $(this).text("Hide");
    });
    $(document).on('click', ".hide", function(){
        $(".content").hide();
        $(this).addClass("show");
        $(this).removeClass("hide");
        $(this).text("Show");
    });
</script>
```

You should also use the toggleClass() method @mplungjan suggests.

Here's the jQuery docs for the on() function https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Is this not the same as my second solution?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now I know why my code wasn't working.

Comment: You're absolutely right @mplungjan, I should have read your response more thoroughly before posting my own.

Answer (score -1):

```js
$("#show-hide").toggle(function() {
  $(".content").hide();
  $(this).text("Show");
}, function() {
  $(".content").show();
  $(this).text("Hide");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="content">If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>
<button id="show-hide">Hide</button>
```

Comment: Make a snippet and test it. Your toggle is not what you think it is

Comment: sorry, toggle is an animation now in jQuery. I guess the next best thing from my point of view is toggleClass.

Comment: Has been for years